# Excel spreadsheet vlookup

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup

I am struggling with guidance I have seen here and in ChatGPT. I have a simple spreadsheet, here is what I am trying to accomplish.
Thousands of rows of data...I have data in 4 rows and I am trying to do the following:
In column C, I am trying to say: if the zip code in column B matches the Zip code in Column K, the place the State listed in Column J in the appropriate cell in Row C. Any help would be awesome.

Tried google searches and Chatgpt and I cannot get their suggestions to work.

Comment: tell me if i am wrong- lets say cell B1 zip code and the zip code in cell K1 If both match then the functions returns the cell J1 that has state listed in to c1  . Otherwise nothing ?

Comment: You need to use an XLOOKUP instead of VLOOKUP, a vlookup cannot search a column to the left. An xlookup you define the search and return arrays seperately. This is likely what's causing your issues.

Comment: If you don't have MS365, in e.g. cell `C2` use `=IFNA(INDEX(J$2:J$51,MATCH(B2,K$2:K$51,0)),"")` and copy down.

Answer (score 0):

What's snagging your vlookup is it cannot search from right to left. J comes before K, so when you highlight your table, the vlookup is searching column J and not finding any matches, and probably producing #N/A. Either you need to move the column to the right of the zip codes or use an XLOOKUP, if you're on 365.

Xlookup's are very similar to a vlookup but with a few additional features. You define the search criteria the same way, but the difference is you bring in the column you want to search (col K) and the column you want the results from (col J) seperately. Then you can define the exact match and the order to search, but you likely want to set these both to 0.

Assuming your data starts at B2

`=xlookup(B2, $K:$K, $J:$J, 0, 0 )`

If you flipped the zip codes to column J and the states to column K

`=vlookup(b2,$J:$K,2,0)`

edit: with zip code column formatted as text, the search criteria is likely a number, you address this by changing the formula to include a `TEXT` function.

`=xlookup( text(B2,"00000"), $K:$K, $J:$J, 0, 0 )`

`=vlookup( text(B2,"00000") ,$J:$K,2,0)`

If your zipcodes are formatted differently and you need to be able to search for a fuller zip code you can change the text function to be `TEXT(B2, "00000-0000")`. If it can be both you can write the whole function to include an IF.

`=xlookup( if( len(b2) > 5, text(b2, "00000-0000"), text(b2, "00000")), K:K, J:J, 0, 0)`

Comment: Ok, i flipped J and K and entered =vlookup(b2,$J:$K,2,0)...the response is #n/a

Comment: Confirm that the data is formatted the same, the zip codes could be stored as text.

Comment: Putting J and K back to where they were and using the xlookup returns a 0

Comment: If you can manually find that zip code in the range, it is likely due to a mismatch in the data formatting. Likely numbers stored as text and you're searching for a number against that text range.

Comment: Both columns are labled as numbers

Comment: @DerrickGirard you may see a little green tab in the corner of a cell. It can be stored as text but still appear formatted as a number. If you're not finding a match either it's not in the dataset or there's a type mismatch.

Comment: ah, i think that's right...let me see how i can change that

Comment: What you want to change is in the xlookup is this: `=xlookup( text(B2,"00000"), $K:$K, $J:$J, 0, 0 )` which will take your number zip code and format it as text before searching.

Comment: is there a way to do that for an entire column?

Comment: awesome, i'll try that quick

Comment: Hopefully that does the trick! If the numbers are formatted differently. you can just adjust that "00000" accordingly.

Comment: Do you know how to reduce zip codes that have the -0000 after? Some have this, some don't and this is causing an issue

Comment: I would add another column that looks at that zip code column and trims it off with `=LEFT( K2, 5 )` (assumes your zip codes are 5-digits, change accordingly), of course change the reference to look at this new column instead. If you need to search and the search zip is similar, you can change the text formula to `TEXT( B2, "00000-0000")`

Comment: @DerrickGirard did this work out for you?